# How does one uninstall Ubuntu?

Tags: uninstall

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my HP laptop and I formatted the partition which had Windows 8.1. So Ubuntu could have all the hard drive space. Is there a way I could uninstall Ubuntu and reinstall Windows 8.1?

Comment: If you do not want to keep Ubuntu around, just re-install Windows from the CD and choose to wipe out the whole disk.

Answer (score 1):

Just reinstall windows 8.1 on your HP PC and your good to go else create a partition for backup, backup your files in that partition (Ensure it's readable through Windows) and then replace Ubuntu with Windows 8.1 That should perform the magic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gparted](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) to view the hdd portion (if you want you can just recreate the partitions) 
And reinstall windows 8.1 on your HP PC.